# Difference of JMS/MQ and a synchronized method

Tags: jms

I understood that JMS is used to process synch messages, so what is the difference to use JMS or just take something like that?

```
public void synchronized doSomething(Message message) {
    //do something sync
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually not sure what you mean by "synch messages". The key concept behind JMS is asynchronous messaging. So a sender/publisher simply calls `send(Message)` which is a non-blocking call. It thus does not need to wait for the receiver/consumer to finish processing.